# Rails 3 Query Help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How can I use LIKE in a query? The reason I want to do this is because I have this query that checks to make sure the form type AND state are correct, but I would like it to not be case sensitive. Here is what I have

```
@fields = Field.where(:form_type => 1, :state => "Alaska")
```

Also how can I make it so that if the `form_type = 1 OR form_type = *` it still returns results?

Comment: Yeah the alaska part is not supped to be case sensitive. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use this format:

```
@fields = Field.where(:form_type => 1).where("state LIKE 'Alaska'")
```

Comment: could i do this? @fields = Field.where("form_type = ? OR form_type =?, 1, *).where("state LIKE 'Alaska'")

Comment: Are you using the asterisk to mean "any form type", or is * an actual valid value for it?

Comment: There is no guarantee that LIKE will be case insensitive. MySQL's LIKE will usually be case insensitive but PostgreSQL's won't be (and PostgreSQL offers an ILIKE operator for case insensitive matching).

Comment: well thats not a problem. But can you help me with the OR problem i'm having. How can i make a query that says "grab the form_types that are equal to 1 OR * WHERE the state is alaska?

Comment: You would just say `.where(:form_type => [1, "*"]).where("state like 'Alaska'")`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like writing raw SQL in your code, but you want to use `LIKE` clauses in your queries, the `squeel` gem is very nice.  http://metautonomo.us/projects/squeel/

I have used the gem with MySQL and PostreSQL and it generates the proper SQL (LIKE for MySQL and ILIKE for Postgres).  Your query with squeel would look something like this:

```
@fields = Field.where{(form_type.in [1,2,3]) & (state =~ 'Alaska'")}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be case insensitive and [allow `form_type` to be 1 or 3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions), you could do it like this:

```
@fields = Field.where(:form_type => [1,3]).where("LOWER(state) = 'alaska'")
```

Or, if you like shouting (and who doesn't like a bit of shouting now and then?):

```
@fields = Field.where(:form_type => [1,3]).where("UPPER(state) = 'ALASKA'")
```

The individual `.where` calls are combined with AND and the most reliable way to get consistent case behavior is to do it yourself.

Comment: thank you. do you know how i could query if the form_type is equal to 1 or 3?